# Why is systemd ignoring my power button?

Tags: linux, systemd, power-management, acpi

When I press the power button nothing happens. System logs show that the kernel is detecting the button without issue:

```
input: Power button as /devices/...
ACPI: Power button [PWRB]
```

Why isn't systemd detecting my power button and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

The systemd service `systemd-logind` is responsible for handling ACPI signals. First make sure the service is running

```
systemctl status systemd-logind
```

If this service is inactive due to a failed "condition check", make sure that dbus is installed and running then try to start the service manually: `systemctl start systemd-logind`

If the service runs and you see a few "Watching system buttons .." messages in `systemd-logind`'s logs, then systemd should be monitoring your power button. You should check that  `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` isn't changing  how systemd handles power button signals.

If systemd still doesn't respond to your power button, make sure that `acpid` isn't installed and isn't interfering with your system's ACPI events.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, +1! If `acpid` is installed, you can check likewise if it is enabled wtih `systemctl status acpid`, and confirm or not its interference with `acpi_listen`. You can then deactivate `acpid` it or keep it and create a rule for that key.